# How to recover frm and ibd files?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I had a monster problem after the lack of space by mysql-slow and it ended and apparently MariaDB stopped working because it corrupted something in the bank.

Luckily I made a backup of / var / lib / mysql and managed to recover 27 of the 30 databases as follows:

1. I made a tar.gz of / var / lib / mysql /
2. I stopped the mariadb
3. I deleted everything inside / var / lib / mysql.
4. tar -zxvf mysql.tar.gz generated
5. rm -rf aria_log. *

> I also changed my.cnf to p

After that when I run `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

It allows me to give a mysqldump of the bases but the last 3 databases gives several errors:

> mysqldump Got error: 1932: "- doesn't exist in engine" when using
> LOCK TABLES
>
> mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
> when dumping table

**There is little left to recover everything. Can someone help me?**

*Ps I advise you to always set up a backup on VM Google as it does not do it alone. I almost lost my life because of that.*

Comment: Did you check if all files in /var/lib/mysql have the correct permissions (usually mysql.mysql)? Did you try to run mysqldump with --skip-lock-tables ?

Comment: I tried to see the permissions. I tried to delete / mysql / mysql / * too, I ran mysqldump with --skip-lock-tables and nothing works ;(